# wxPython - Bitmap button won´t be destroyed

Tags: button, bitmap, wxpython, destroy

I have problem with bitmap button, I want t odestroy it, but it´s still showing after i click on wbtn, it just prints Destroyed. Here is code:

```
    import wx

class GameFrame(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self,parent,id):

    self.shutdown_showing = False

    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "Project - Map", size=(860, 640))
    wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
    self.SetBackgroundColour("green")

    self.wndwsbtn = wx.Bitmap("Images/wlogo.png")
    self.wbtn = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, self.wndwsbtn)
    self.wbtn.SetPosition((2, 585))
    self.wbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.wstart)
    self.wbtn.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Start"))

def wstart(self, event):

    if self.shutdown_showing:
        self.shutdownbtn.Destroy()
        self.Layout()
        print "Destroyed"
        self.shutdown_showing = False

    if not self.shutdown_showing:
        self.shutdownbtn = wx.Bitmap("Images/wstdwn.png")
        self.wstdwnbtn = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, self.shutdownbtn)
        self.wstdwnbtn.SetPosition((0, 550))
        self.wstdwnbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.wexit)
        self.wstdwnbtn.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Exit to main menu."))
        self.shutdown_showing = True

def wexit(self, event):
    print "Exit"

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame=GameFrame(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I think my destroy code isn´t wrong, so i really don´t know why it´s still showing button and print Deystroyed if i click on wbtn. Please help somebody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of your question you want to destroy/remove the `self.wstdwnbtn` when you click on the `wbtn`.

Well my approach is to create the `self.wstdwnbtn` on the `wbtn`. This can be done by following line:

```
self.wstdwnbtn = wx.StaticBitmap(self.wbtn, -1, self.shutdownbtn)
```

Because in your code

`self.wstdwnbtn = wx.StaticBitmap(self.wbtn, -1, self.shutdownbtn)`

you cannot click the `self.wstdwnbtn`. Clicking on `self.wstdwnbtn` doesn't produced 'Exit' in your case. But my I fixed that too.

More over I found an other logical problem in your code. You are using a variable `self.shutdown_showing` to determine when to destroy the `self.wstdwnbtn`. Your current logic is as below:

> If `self.shutdown_showing` is True, then destroy `self.wstdwnbtn` and set `self.shutdown_showing` = False
>
> If `self.shutdown_showing` is False, then you are again creating a
> `self.wstdwnbtn` and set `self.shutdown_showing` = True

So, initially the  `self.shutdown_showing` = False, so you simply create `self.wstdwnbtn`. then you set `self.shutdown_showing` = True. So, next time when you click on `self.wbtn` the `wstart()` is called. Now as the `self.shutdown_showing` = True, so due to your logic it destroys the `self.wstdwnbtn` and set the `self.shutdown_showing` = False. On next line you have `if not self.shutdown_showing:` so as the `self.shutdown_showing` = False you again create a `self.wstdwnbtn` immediately, so you never see the `self.wstdwnbtn` getting destroyed.

**Solution**:

I think you wanted to use [if-Else](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) statement. I have fixed your code for all these problems. Now you'll see how the `self.wstdwnbtn` gets destroyed and created again.

```
import wx

class GameFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):

        self.shutdown_showing = False
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "Project - Map", size=(860, 640))
        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("green")
        self.wndwsbtn = wx.Bitmap("Your Image")
        self.wbtn = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, self.wndwsbtn)
        self.wbtn.SetPosition((2, 585))
        self.wbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.wstart)
        self.wbtn.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Start"))

    def wstart(self, event):
        if self.shutdown_showing:
            self.wstdwnbtn.Destroy()# Destroy self.wstdwnbtn
            self.Layout()
            print "Destroyed"
            self.shutdown_showing = False
        # if not self.shutdown_showing: This was wrong.
        else:
            self.shutdownbtn = wx.Bitmap("Your image")
            # Create self.wstdwnbtn on self.wbtn instead.
            self.wstdwnbtn = wx.StaticBitmap(self.wbtn, -1, self.shutdownbtn)
            self.wstdwnbtn.SetPosition((0, 550))
            self.wstdwnbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.wexit)
            self.wstdwnbtn.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Exit to main menu."))
            self.shutdown_showing = True

    def wexit(self, event):
        print "Exit"

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame=GameFrame(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, it helped me much. If code is just like this it works, but i have code with more imported bitmaps and if i give code there and click wbtn it i can´t see wstdwnbtn, but if i click for second time it prints Destroyed. So wstdwnbtn is there, but i can´t see it.

Comment: I have already answered your this particular question. If you still have some enquiry then either ask a new question or please edit your current question with the proper code and details. Else it is not possible to know what your problem is?